# Send "git pull" to background in a for loop in a bash script

Tags: bash

Every day I have to pull around 100 repos, which I have automated with a script. This takes quite a long time when done sequentually, so I want to do this in parallel by sending each "git pull" to the background. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e -u

START=$(date +%s)

export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs)

allRepos=$(curl  \
  -s \
  -f \
  --user "${githubUser:?}:${githubApiKey:?}" \
  --header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --request GET https://internalgithuburl/api/v3/user/repos?per_page=1000 | \
  jq -r '.[]' | \
  grep ssh_url | \
  sed 's/  "ssh_url": "//' | \
  sed 's/",//'
  )
amountAllRepos=$(echo "$allRepos" | wc -w | xargs)

echo "$amountAllRepos Repositories found."

cd "/home/mles/projectdir"

repoCounter=1

for repo in $allRepos; do
  echo "Checking $repo ($repoCounter/$amountAllRepos)"

  repoDirectory=$(basename "$repo" ".git")

  if [ -d "$repoDirectory" ]; then
    echo "  Already cloned. Updating"
    cd "$repoDirectory"
    git reset --hard --quiet
    git pull 2>&1 | sed 's/^/  /' &
    cd ..
  else
    echo "  New Repo found. Cloning"
    git clone --quiet "$repo"
  fi

  repoCounter=$((repoCounter + 1))

done

cd "/home/mles"

END=$(date +%s)
DIFF=$(( $END - $START ))
echo "It took ${DIFF} seconds"
```

Notice the  `&` at the end of `git pull`. If I run this, it looks like as it is still done sequentually:

```
Checking git@githubdomain:group/proxytest.git (1/97)
  Already cloned. Updating
Checking git@githubdomain:group/buildserver-compose.git (2/97)
  Already cloned. Updating
  Already up to date.
Checking git@githubdomain:group/concourse-gate-resource.git (3/97)
  Already cloned. Updating
  Already up to date.
Checking git@githubdomain:group/concourse-teams.git (4/97)
  Already cloned. Updating
Checking git@githubdomain:group/container-base-image.git (5/97)
  Already cloned. Updating
  Already up to date.
  Already up to date.
Checking git@githubdomain:group/container-build-images.git (6/97)
  Already cloned. Updating
  Already up to date.
Checking git@githubdomain:group/container-build-npm.git (7/97)
  Already cloned. Updating
  Already up to date.
Checking git@githubdomain:group/container-elasticsearch.git (8/97)
  Already cloned. Updating
  Already up to date.
Checking git@githubdomain:group/container-grafana.git (9/97)
  Already cloned. Updating
  Already up to date.
Checking git@githubdomain:group/container-haproxy.git (10/97)
  Already cloned. Updating
  Already up to date.
```

Also it takes the same time as done sequentually. This script runs for 1896 seconds sequentually, and it takes 1804 seconds with this modification in parallel.

How can I really run the all the "git pull" commands in parallel?

Comment: Are you sure that it's the _pull_ which takes most of the time? Why not putting the whole loop body into background?

Comment: [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) might be useful. But first you need to make sure where the bottleneck is. If it's disk I/O or network bandwidth, then parallelization is more likely to harm than help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to also run `git reset --hard --quiet` and `git clone` in the background? Try maybe:

```bash
for repo in $allRepos; do

  printf 'Checking %s (%d/%d)\n' "$repo" "$repoCounter" "$amountAllRepos"

  repoDirectory="${repo%.git}"
  repoDirectory="${repoDirectory##*/}"

  if [ -d "$repoDirectory" ]; then
    printf '  Already cloned. Updating\n'
    { git -C "$repoDirectory" reset --hard --quiet &&
      git -C "$repoDirectory" pull 2>&1 |
      sed 's/^/  /'; } &
  else
    printf '  New Repo found. Cloning\n'
    git clone --quiet "$repo" &
  fi

  (( repoCounter += 1))

done
```

Note the use of bash builtin instead of `basename` and the `git -C` instead of `cd`, this should probably speedup a bit.

But all this means that you will launch many jobs in parallel, probably more than the number of cores on your computer. There is a risk that it becomes less responsive. A better approach would probably be to use a parallel-capable tool like `xargs`, `GNU make` or `GNU parallel`. It would allow you to control the maximum number of jobs that run at the same time. Example with `xargs`:

```bash
# first define and export a function to process one repository
# $1: total, $2: repository, $3: count

updateRepo() {
  printf 'Checking %s (%d/%d)\n' "$2" "$3" "$1"
  dir="${2%.git}"; dir="${dir##*/}"
  if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
    printf '  Already cloned. Updating\n'
    git -C "$dir" reset --hard --quiet
    git -C "$dir" pull 2>&1 | sed 's/^/  /' 
  else
    printf '  New Repo found. Cloning\n'
    git clone --quiet "$2"
  fi
}
export -f updateRepo

# build a bash indexed array (repos) in which 2 consecutive cells
# contain the repository and the count

declare -a repos=() tmp=( $allRepos )
declare -i n=1 t="${#tmp[@]}"

for repo in "${tmp[@]}"; do
  repos+=( "$repo" "$n" )
  (( n += 1 ))
done

# pass the array to xargs, 2 entries at a time (-n2), with,
# e.g., up to 8 jobs in parallel (-P8), and let it use our
# function to process each repository

printf '%s\n' "${repos[@]}" | xargs -P8 -n2 bash -c 'updateRepo "$@"' "bash" "$t"
```

For each pair of array cells (`repository`, `count`) `xargs` will launch `bash` with script `updateRepo "$@"` and parameters `$0="bash"`, `$1="$t"`, `$2=repository`, `$3=count` (`"$t"` is the total number of repositories computed above). It will first launch 8 of them and as soon as one finishes it will launch a new one, always keeping 8 running jobs, until the end.

Of course, whatever method you use, the output will be mixed up. If this is a problem you can modify the `updateRepo` function to print only the first message on the standard output and send everything else in a separate log file (e.g., `$3.log`).

Comment: Hei, that's quite an elaborate solution, thanks! You were right, the problem is that it waits for the `git reset --hard` command to complete. Sending both in the background works. CPU goes to 100%, but it's not becoming unresponsive. Now I have the problem that I don't know when all the background tasks finish. I will have to identify the background processes and then check how many are still running.